# Преобразование длинной ссылки в короткую

Tags: php, алгоритм, url, преобразование, shortcode

Подскажите алгоритм преобразования длинных URL в короткие.
Например на входе строка с длинным URL:

`$str = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=goiogle&oq=goiogle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8';`

На выходе короткая:

```
http://surl.li/balo
```

Синтаксис желательно php или js или python

На примере нашёл [онлайн сервис](https://hyperhost.ua/tools/ru/surli)

Comment: Генерируете/ищете уникальный id > Записываете в базу id и ссылку > отдаете пользователю. При заходе на сайт ищете id и редиректите по нужному направлению.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не много не понятно. Как генерировать? И не понятно как браузер узнаёт по это ссылке куда перенаправлять?

Comment: Как генерировать - как вашей душе угодно, любое случайное, уникальное значение. Браузер нечего не узнает, сайт при получение этого id, сверяет его с базой своей и если там такой есть, то берет из базы ссылку и перенаправляет туда.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, правильно понял, что короткая ссылка будет вести на домен с реализацией этого сервиса? Если мой домен http://test.com, то сгенерированная ссылка будет в таком формате? http://test.com/GEneRaTELinK ?

Comment: Ну а как вы еще хотели?) Ваше "сокращение", ваш код, ваш сервер.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ напишите в ответ, утвержу :) понял алгоритм, спасибо

Comment: Это я оставлю на вас. Отвечайте сами, написав то, что в итоге поняли и получили.

Comment: https://bookflow.ru/kak-rabotayut-sokrashhateli-ssylok/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Проверяем роут на цель обращение

   - `http://domain/`  - генерация короткого url + пункт 2
   - `http://domain/*/` - редирект на ссылку + пункт 3
2. Получаем ссылку из формы
3. Проверяем ссылку на существование в бд

   - Если существует    - перенаправляем на оригинальную ссылку
   - Если не существует - (пункт 4)
4. Проверяем `token` на совпадение в бд

   - Совпадение найдено - генерируем новое + пункт 3
   - Совпадений нет     - записываем `token` и оригинальную ссылку + пункт 5
5. Выводим во фронт

> Спасибо за объяснение в комментариях @EvgeniyZ

#### Прошу учесть, что алгоритм полностью рабочий, но не оптимизирован